# retain message in sqs even after read

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, amazon-sqs

I've a `Airflow` Dag, which runs for multiple tables processing, but for one table at a time. Dag instances run in parallel if need to run more than one table processing.

My problem is, I need to send message when processing of some specific tables are completed, then send kinesis message.

For example, I've total 5 tables (a,b,c,d,e), But I need to send message only when processing of (a,b,c,e) are completed.

Dag instance gets triggered via lambda function, to process any specific table.

Is there any way I could send message only when processing of tables `(a,b,c,e)` are completed ?

I was thinking to push message in `SQS` after every processing of table in specific Dag instance. And after pushing message, check that If it finds all tables names in `SQS`, In case If it finds all table names in it, will send Kinesis message and empty the `SQS`.

If Any running Dag instance, find all table names in SQL, should be able to emptying SQS.

Please suggest ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to send SQS update as soon as any table(a,b,c,e) is updated check the entry in the rest table. Once you find the entry in all required table just publish the kinesis event.

This will help you on avoiding the checking every message in SQS and also no need to handle the SQS deletion and addition of message extrenally.

Comment: I need to send only one message once all table processing is done

Comment: THat whay I'm saying, once you received the last message for which all the table has entry in it you can publish the message. Even if you received update from one of the message for table (a,b,c,e), you are checking the rest db and this will help in sending the update to kinesis.

Comment: sequence is not guaranteed

Comment: but you don't need to maintain the sequence right? What you need is to have update in all the table. 

Even if you want sequence : FIFO SQS will help as it guarantees the sequence delivery

Comment: Listen to every event from required table and once you find that all the table is having entry only that time you can post the kinesis eevnt